# busybox network configuration script error

Tags: linux, shell, busybox

Hello I have the script in the start up but I don't get why it is showing error on execution

```
#!/bin/sh

# Starting the network interface

PATH="/sbin:/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/sbin"


FILENAME="/etc/ipconf"
count=0

while read LINE
do
  ipValues[count]=$(echo $LINE |  awk -F'=' '{print $2}')
  count=`expr $count + 1`
done < $FILENAME

echo "Setting up IP Address"
ifconfig eth0 up
ifconfig eth0 ${ipValues[0]} netmask ${ipValues[1]}
echo "IP :: ${ipValues[0]} SUBNET MASK :: ${ipValues[1]}"
route add default gw ${ipValues[2]}
echo "Default Gateway :: ${ipValues[2]}"

echo "Network configured properly"

exit 0
```

Here is my ipconf file

```
IPADDRESS=192.168.1.13
SUBNETMASK=255.255.255.0
GATEWAY=192.168.1.220
```

And here is my scripts error

```
ipValues[count]=192.168.1.13 Not found
ipValues[count]=255.255.255.0 Not found
ipValues[count]=192.168.1.220 Not found
Setting up IP Address
Line 20 syntax error: Bad substitution
```

My script is braking in line `ifconfig eth0 ${ipValues[0]} netmask ${ipValues[1]}`. Is this array assignment is correct or busybox scripts needs different approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're right, busybox doesn't support the array syntax in your script.

In order to set the values, you might use

```
eval ipValues$count=$(echo $LINE |  awk -F'=' '{print $2}')
```

and to read the variables

```
ifconfig eth0 ${ipValues0} netmask ${ipValues1}
echo "IP :: ${ipValues0} SUBNET MASK :: ${ipValues1}"
route add default gw ${ipValues2}
echo "Default Gateway :: ${ipValues2}"
```